# Get link to image file at Parse.com

Tags: android, image, file, parse-platform

I have File column in my table.

The file represents image.

File is ok, and I can [get it as byte array.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503689/get-file-from-parseobject)

Can I get a direct (web) link to this image?

Comment: Where you have stored the link for the image???

Comment: Please read my question again, I need a link to an existing image at Parse.com table

Comment: Perhaps your question is not so clear or perhaps I, like Raja, can not understand how you get the image as byte array from parse.com in the first place?

Comment: This is how to get the image as byte array from parse.com : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14503689/get-file-from-parseobject

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can obtain the URL of a file using the `getUrl()` method. So if `imageFile` is a `ParseFile`, you would get the URL in this manner:

```
imageFile.getUrl();
```

Comment: is it safe to share file link? Because i can see my server's external ip and app id on the link it generates

Answer (score 1):

`getUrl()` no longer works. Instead use the following.

```
var imageURL = imageFile.url();
```