# Sharing an image using parse.com

Tags: iphone, ios, image, parse-platform

I would like to share an image between two users using parse.com. My original idea was to simple pass the image url from the first user to the second to view/download. I have no issue uploading the image to parse.com , however I can't work out how to return the url. Is it possible to return the url?

There seems to be a solution for this on android [Get link to image file at Parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562595/get-link-to-image-file-at-parse-com) but I can't find one for iphone.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in iPhone too there there'll be something similar to android one, check.

Comment: Thanks rptwsthi, that was a hopeless question turns out I was trying to retrieve the url on a PFObject not PFFile. Duh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Image save](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/SavingImagesTutorial) example of Parse.com, I found the image url.

In `- (void)setUpImages:(NSArray *)images` method,

`PFFile *theImage = [eachObject objectForKey:@"imageFile"];` will return image file object with its URL.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Correct. The URL is at [theImage url];